# Creating a subsite using c# and the REST API

Tags: 2013, rest

Im trying to create a site using the REST API from a console app.  I keep getting:

> "Not well formed JSON Stream"

I cant find much on calling the REST API from c# so have been piecing it together from the scaps I could find.  Below is my code.  Any idea?

```
RestClient RC = new RestClient("http://someserver/_api");
            NetworkCredential NCredential = new NetworkCredential("somelogin", "somepassword", "somedomain");
            RC.Authenticator = new NtlmAuthenticator(NCredential);

            RestRequest Request = new RestRequest("contextinfo?$select=FormDigestValue", Method.POST);
            Request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
            Request.AddHeader("Body", "");

            //rethink this!!!!!!!!
            string ReturnedStr = RC.Execute(Request).Content;
            int StartPos = ReturnedStr.IndexOf("FormDigestValue") + 18;
            int length = ReturnedStr.IndexOf(@""",", StartPos) - StartPos;
            string FormDigestValue = ReturnedStr.Substring(StartPos, length);

            Console.WriteLine(FormDigestValue);

            string Data = string.Concat(
                "{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.WebCreationInformation' },",
                "'Title': 'Team projects', 'Url': 'TeamProjects', 'WebTemplate': 'STS'",
                "'UseSamePermissionsAsParentSite': true }");

            Request = new RestRequest("web/webs/add", Method.POST);
            Request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
            Request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json;odata=verbose");
            Request.AddHeader("content-length", Data.Length.ToString());
            Request.AddHeader("X-RequestDigest", FormDigestValue);
            Request.AddParameter("parameters", Data);

            Console.WriteLine("Creating Site");
            Console.WriteLine(RC.Execute(Request).Content);
            Console.WriteLine("Created Site");
            Console.ReadLine();
```

**UPDATE**
It seems I had a typo in my JSON string.  Fixing this sorted the "well formatted json" error, however it still doesn't work as expected.  I found by adding a parameter and specifying that the string is of type `"application/json;odata=verbose"` sorted the problem.

```
RestClient RC = new RestClient("http://grpcphsp02d:1819/_api");
            NetworkCredential NCredential = new NetworkCredential("SomeUserName", "SomePassword", "SomeDomain");
            RC.Authenticator = new NtlmAuthenticator(NCredential);

            RestRequest Request = new RestRequest("contextinfo?$select=FormDigestValue", Method.POST);
            Request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
            Request.AddHeader("Body", "");

            //rethink this!!!!!!!!
            string ReturnedStr = RC.Execute(Request).Content;
            int StartPos = ReturnedStr.IndexOf("FormDigestValue") + 18;
            int length = ReturnedStr.IndexOf(@""",", StartPos) - StartPos;
            string FormDigestValue = ReturnedStr.Substring(StartPos, length);

            Console.WriteLine(FormDigestValue);

            var Data = string.Concat(
                "{'parameters':{'__metadata':{'type':'SP.WebCreationInformation'},",
                "'Title':'Team projects 3','Url':'TeamProjects3','WebTemplate':'STS',",
                "'UseSamePermissionsAsParentSite': true}}");

            Request = new RestRequest("web/webs/add", Method.POST);
            Request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            Request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
            Request.AddHeader("X-RequestDigest", FormDigestValue);
            Request.AddParameter("application/json;odata=verbose", Data, ParameterType.RequestBody);

            Console.WriteLine("Creating Site");
            Console.WriteLine(RC.Execute(Request).Content);
            Console.WriteLine("Created Site");
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I suggest that you consider using the Client Object Model instead of the REST API when writing managed code. The code will be a lot cleaner, and it will be easier to debug and maintain. You'll also be working with real types instead of raw XML or JSON.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used C# to do REST calls in awhile, but when I did, I used the `HttPWebRequest`, as that's what I found on MSDN:

```
var Data = string.Concat(
            "{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.WebCreationInformation' },",
            "'Title': 'Team projects', 'Url': 'TeamProjects', 'WebTemplate': 'STS'",
            "'UseSamePermissionsAsParentSite': true }");
var endpointRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://<site url>/_api/Web/webs/add");
endpointRequest.Method = "POST";
endpointRequest.ContentLength = Data.Length;
endpointRequest.ContentType = "application/json;odata=verbose";
endpointRequest.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
endpointRequest.Headers.Add("X-RequestDigest", digest);
var stream = endpointRequest.GetRequestStream();
stream.Write(Data, 0, Data.Length);
stream.Close();

var endpointResponse = (HttpWebResponse)endpointRequest.GetResponse();
```

I've been using JavaScript for REST lately, so there may be slight errors, but I believe I got it right.  See [this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/officeapps/SharePoint-2013-Perform-335d925b/sourcecode?fileId=77297&pathId=614432390) for some code examples.