# Create sub-site in SharePoint Online without using SharePoint Client Model in C#

Tags: development, sharepoint-online, sub-site

I am trying to create a sub-site in SharePoint Online using REST APIs in C#. 
I don't want to use Microsoft.SharePoint.Client as the use of this DLL requires installation of SharePoint Client Components on the client server.

I have referred the following links-
- [Creating a subsite using c# and the REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/109639/creating-a-subsite-using-c-and-the-rest-api)
- http://newscentral.exsees.com/item/b0573efe00a1433a46363be62b854e94-a466156e0e826abb252152049ba40f1e

But, I am getting the following error-
- the remote server returned an error 403 forbidden
Is there any way to solve this problem?

Or is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is happening because of cross domain issue. To resolve this you should pass extra details to the REST EndPoints as explained on below thread

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25010655/rest-post-call-with-authentication-token

Comment: Hi Amal, thanks your quick reply. Can you please share the entire code if possible?